# Bootstrap modalbox loop problem in boostrap table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I cant get loop with that code from boostrap for my modalboxes... But I can get loop if I delete `<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal">`  without Modalbox.. if I delete that code, of course all datatables shown at same time without any modalbox... how can I fixt that ?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script src="assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>FMH44-v1.0</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->


    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/octicons/4.4.0/font/octicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lightbox/dist/css/lightbox.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <link href="assets/switch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="assets/sticky.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head> 

<?php

include('database_connection.php');

$sorgu = $baglanti->query("SELECT * FROM makale ORDER BY sevk_tarihi ASC, boya_kodu_sistem");
while ($sonuc = $sorgu->fetch_assoc())  {
?>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?>">İŞ FORMU</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?>">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" >deneme  </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"id="printThis">



      <form method="post" id="insert_form">  

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm table-bordered">

<tr>
<td colspan="10"  class="table-danger" ><center><?php $proje= $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ; echo substr(".'$proje'.",11,-2);  ?>  / (PROJE BİLGİSİ) </center></td>
</tr>


</table>

</form>
</div></div></div></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I updated code.. but now it gives error for : "nothing happen when I push the button"

Comment: `class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">` That `>` shouldn't be there. `class="modal-dialog>` This `>` however should a `"`

Comment: "_same data from mysql with that code_" There is nothing in "_that code_" that would gather any data from MySQL

Comment: ">" they are about copy paste problem to here... not exact codes is like those.. I edited them.

Comment: I didnt put down mysql codes. I thought not necesarry.. Because.. if I delete 

<div class="modal fade" id="MYMODAL">

That div.. they are shown as not table but modalbox, But each data for each row no problem...

Comment: Please provide some more code. Your question is about a "loop problem in bootstrap table", but your code only shows part of a modal.

Comment: Ok I just didnt want to confuse question.. But I will edit code.

Comment: I updated  code with full version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

the problem is :

```
data-target="#<?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?>"

id="<?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?>"
```

I tried like that but I dont know why code doesnt work with that way.

But after add any letter at the begin of the code like that :

```
    data-target="#MYMODEL<?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?>"

    id="MYMODEL<?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?>"
```

The code works...

But be carefull :

```
<?php echo $sonuc['proje_ismi'] ?>
```

That code must be uniq and also there wont be any "space" otherwise doesnt work..

So if you can do prefer  `MYMODAL<?php echo $sonuc['ID']?>` it is better...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of missing closing `</div>` tags after `</form>`. This is breaking your document structure. Inserting `</div></div></div></div>` at the end of the loop should fix this.

In addition, each modal has the same id `mymodal` inside the loop (this is also the case for your forms, which all have the same id `insert_form`). This might lead to some problems with the bootstrap JavaScript, because there is no unique modal for each button in the tables. You should make sure, that each id is used only once for the page. You can insert counter and create unique ids like `mymodal-1`, `mymodal-2`... to avoid this.

Comment: I updated code.. but now it gives error for : "nothing happen when I push the button"

Comment: What are the contents of your id `$sonuc['proje_ismi']`? Make sure that there is no space in this string.